# Minoration of an expectation

Tags: probability, inequality, logarithms

I'm working on the next exercise, it's an excerpt from an Oral HEC

$X$ is a random variable defined on a probabilistic space $(Ω, A, P)$ that follows the uniform law on $[a, b]$
with $1≤a <b$     prove that   $E(X+\frac{1}{X})\ge a+\dfrac{1}{a}$
to show that :
$E(X+\frac{1}{X}) \ge a+\dfrac{1}{a}$

Indeed
$$E\left(X+\frac{1}{X}\right)= \int_a^b \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)\,dx = \frac{a+b}2 + \frac{\ln(b)-\ln(a)}{b-a}$$

as $(a+b)/2 >a$  a and $\frac{\ln (b) -\ln (a)}{b-a} = 1 / c$ by the theorem of finite increments

it is larger than $a$, so $1/c$ is smaller than $a.$ I get an inequality that is not in the right direction there may be another way to achieve good inequality.

Comment: what is the question ?..

Comment: 1<=a<b    prove that   $E(X+\frac{1}{X})>=a+\frac{1}{a}$

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x):=x+1/x$. Then $f'(x)=1-1/x^2$. So on $[a,b]$ with $a\geq 1$, $f$ is monotonically increasing, hence $f\geq f(a)=a+1/a$. It follows that $E[X+1/X]\geq E[a+1/a]=a+1/a$.